# div class not affecting separate div id when it should be

Tags: html, css

I have a status information bar (`.nav-infobar__container`) within the navigation of my website which, when `.active`, must alter it's position **and** decrease the width of another **separate** `div` (`#s_body`).

However, only part of this functionality is working - the position of the status bar is changing, but the width of the other `div` remains the same.

I have tried the following **CSS**:

```
div#s_body{
    position: fixed;
    top: 48px;
    left: 270px;
    width: calc(100% - 270px);
    height: calc(100% - 48px);
    transition: width 213ms;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
.nav-infobar__container.active div#s_body{ // should be affecting #s_body
    width: calc(100% - 650px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-infobar__container{
    position: fixed;
    top: 48px;
    right: -380px;
    width: 379px;
    height: calc(100% - 48px);
    transition: right 213ms;
}
.nav-infobar__container.active{
    right: 0px;
}
```

But to no avail. I want **JavaScript** to be a last resort to this, as I don't want to add more to and already fairly large **JS** site, unnecessarily.

This is the (simplified) **markdown** which I am using:

```
<!-- navigation !-->
<div class="navigation-container">
    <div class="nav-infobar__container">
        <div class="nav-infobar__outer-content">
            <!-- some content !-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- body !-->
<div id="s_body"> <!-- this div should be decreasing in width, but isn't !-->
    <div class="main__fixed-container">
        <!-- some content !-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I have triple-checked over everything, and it all looks fine (as I have done this before); so I'm very confused, at this point.

All help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

In its current form your CSS is not doing what you are expecting. `.nav-infobar__container.active div#s_body` will target a `div` with the id `s_body` when it is a child of `.nav-infobar__container` (and `.nav-infobar__container` also has the class `active`).

### To fix

There is currently no CSS selector that will allow you to target `div#s_body` from `.nav-infobar__container` as they are not siblings so the `active` class will need to be added to `.navigation-container` instead. You can achieve the desired result in CSS by making the following changes:

- Change `.nav-infobar__container.active div#s_body` to `.navigation-container.active+div#s_body`. This rule uses the Adjacent sibling (`+`) selector to target `div#s_body` placed immediately after `.navigation-container`

```js
$(".navigation-container").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
div#s_body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 48px;
  left: 270px;
  width: calc(100% - 270px);
  height: calc(100% - 48px);
  transition: width 213ms;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}

.navigation-container.active+div#s_body {
  width: calc(100% - 650px);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-infobar__container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 48px;
  /*right: -380px;*/
  width: 379px;
  height: calc(100% - 48px);
  transition: right 213ms;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

.nav-infobar__container.active {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- navigation !-->
<div class="navigation-container">
  <div class="nav-infobar__container">
    <div class="nav-infobar__outer-content">
      <!-- some content !-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- body !-->
<div id="s_body">
  <!-- this div should be decreasing in width, but isn't !-->
  <div class="main__fixed-container">
    <!-- some content !-->
  </div>
</div>
```